# Elasticsearch index from csv file

Tags: elasticsearch

I have to setup php project maintaining the elasticsearch server. The client provides me a large txt/csv file with all the data which I want to import(update) in index in elasticsearch. With a bulk operations I have to specify a valid json structure, but I have text file instead.

Is there a way of doing that using the elastic api. Or is there at all such possibility without need of converting the csv file to json

I am totally new for the elastisearch and have difficulties of finding the solution.

Comment: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-load-csv-file-into-elasticsearch-for-visualizaion-in-kibana/61501/8

Comment: Are you open to using Logstash?

Comment: I just found elastica.io lib. I think it will be suitable for my needs. The main reason is, that I have to make interface for the client. Dont want using logstash, kibana and etc... For a relevantly small data, I think this lib will be usefull